# emails are showing perfect in inbox but not in spam

Tags: php, email, cakephp, html-email, email-templates

I am facing a very strange issue that the email which are sending using `cakephp` email are showing perfect if they came in my `inbox` folder but not showing proper when they are in `spam` folder. below are the images

**inbox**

[image]

**Spam**

[image]

what could be the issue.

Comment: Most email services will prevent most styling from rendering if it's flagged as spam, images won't load etc. Your question should be rephrased too "How can I prevent my emails from going to spam" and the answer is simple, send it from an SMTP server (see PHPMailer for example)

Comment: Usually, mail-services strip it of HTML and other content if it's in the spam-folder - it's nothing to do with your mail (aside from the fact that it was flagged as spam), it's a security measure. Just make sure it doesn't go to spam instead ;-)

Comment: Thank you both @Qirel and zanderwar . I am working on preventing spam. this is really a good information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `SPAM` folder full rendering is limited or disabled (for security reasons) - images are not loaded etc.

You should use `text` version of your e-mail, please refer to: [CakeEmail](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html)

And you can use more techniques how to keep your e-mail from out of the spam, e.g. - [10 Tips to Keep Email Out of the Spam Folder](https://sendgrid.com/blog/10-tips-to-keep-email-out-of-the-spam-folder/)

Answer (score 0):

In spam folder, all styling and images are disabled usually.